# "php5-fpm: unrecognized service" and other issues after reverting from PPA

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, php5, php-fpm, apt

Added a repository so that I could move from PHP 5.3 to 5.5 easily in Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. After adding the PPA and following most of the suggestions here https://askubuntu.com/a/109544 it seemed that the PPA didn't handle the upgrade well enough or something was a bit off and things weren't working even after making the necessary config changes post-upgrade.

I removed the PPA and purged a few things and then reinstalled, however things seem even more off now and I can't seem to get back to a proper working state. I backed up all of my configs and have only been trying to get things working as before to no avail. For example:

```
myusername ~ $ sudo service php5-fpm stop
php5-fpm: unrecognized service
myusername ~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop
sudo: /etc/init.d/php5-fpm: command not found
myusername ~ $ ls -al /etc/init.d/php5-fpm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec 12 17:00 /etc/init.d/php5-fpm -> /lib/init/upstart-job
```

I'm not sure how else to go about reverting things, and more than happy to fall back on defaults and drop my configs back but I don't think I've been successful at undoing the upgrade.

How can I repair things, or get things back to a sane working state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to get things back in working order:

1. Backup config files in `/etc/apache2` and `/etc/php5` (sites-available, pools, inis, etc)
2. Remove the old PPA:

   > `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php5`
3. Find all PHP / Apache packages:

   > `dpkg --get-selections | grep 'apache\|php'`
4. Remove all PHP / Apache packges and their config files (you backed things up, right?:

   > `sudo apt-get purge [package name from dpkg list]`
5. Clean apt stuff, for good measure:

   > `sudo apt-get clean`
6. Check the system for PHP and Apache files:

   > `sudo find / -name php; sudo find / -name apache`
7. In my case, there was a symlink in `/etc/init.d` for php-fpm so I removed that:

   > `sudo rm /etc/init.d/php5-fpm`
8. Since the PPA was removed, ran an update:

   > `sudo apt-get update`
9. Reinstalled PHP/Apache:

   > `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php-apc php-fpm`
10. Moved config files back
11. Enabled some Apache mods like `mod_proxy`

And that took a broken, whiny system back into a clean state. Everything's working beautifully again, hope this helps someone.